# CodeEval, First Non-Repeated Character challenge - Need explanation as to why it fails

Tags: c++

I have written a small program in c++ that will take as an input a string.  It will then print the first non-repeated character in the string. Below is my code.  This is for a challenge on CodeEval.com.  The thing is, as far as I can tell, the code works as it's supposed to.  But CodeEval.com tells me my code is not correct.  Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to see the input they're using, but when used at home, I see no problem.  Can anyone tell me if there's anything about my code that does not fit the prompt?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string input = "";
    while(getline(cin, input)){
         vector<char> inputVector(input.begin(),input.end());
         char firstNonRepeatedChar;
         for(int i = 0; i < inputVector.size(); i++){
              if((inputVector[i] != inputVector[i + 1]) && (inputVector[i] != inputVector[i - 1])){
                   firstNonRepeatedChar = inputVector[i];
                   break;
              }
         }
         cout << firstNonRepeatedChar << "\n";
    }
    //system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

EDIT:
This is the code that gave me the right answer, if anyone is wondering.  Ben helped me realize that I wasn't answering the question properly based on the prompt.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int findCharInVector(vector<char>& input, char charToFind);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string input = "";
    while(getline(cin, input)){
         vector<char> characters(input.begin(),input.end());
         char firstNonRepeatedChar;
         for(int i = 0; i < characters.size(); i++){
              if(!(findCharInVector(characters, characters[i]) > 1)){
                   firstNonRepeatedChar = characters[i];
                   break;
              }
         }
         cout << firstNonRepeatedChar << "\n";
    }
    //system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int findCharInVector(vector<char>& input, char charToFind){
    int output = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++){
         if(input[i] == charToFind){
              output++;
         }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: What does non-repeated char mean? In `ababababac` wouldnt the first one be `c` not `a`, also this `(inputVector[i] != inputVector[i - 1])` is very bad news for `i == 0`. `inputVector[-1]` is painful for your pc ...

Comment: here's the link to the challenge, if that helps.   https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/12/

Comment: No link in your comment .... Also this question should really be self contained. Maybe add the defintion of non-repeated to the question.

Comment: I updated it, sorry.  I believe first non-repeated character is just supposed to mean the first character that isn't repeated in a row.  But that's an interesting thought.  Maybe they mean there's only one of that character in the string...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the link in the comments, a non-repeated character is one that only appears in the string once. Here is the example given:

```
yellow // y
tooth  // h
```

Your code:

```
 if((inputVector[i] != inputVector[i + 1]) && (inputVector[i] != inputVector[i - 1])){
               firstNonRepeatedChar = inputVector[i];
```

Is only checking if a character is not repeated *consecutively*. If it was the way you are thinking, then the example above `tooth`, the first non-repeated would be `t`, not `h` as the example specifies.

Furthermore `inputVector[i] != inputVector[i - 1]` will cause undefined behavior for `i == 0`.

Comment: Ben, you are my hero.  What an embarrassing oversight!  Thank you for your help, that was absolutely the answer to my problem.  I also made sure to avoid any 0-1 situations.  Thank you so much! :)